# How to demo a partially structural chimney?

Tags: roof, structural, chimney, demolition

Just bought a new home and would like to remove its chimney. It was originally built on the outside of the home and they built a carport up around it. It looks like it may have sprung a leak, so the top was removed and the rest remains. I would like to tear it down, but am worried the roof is partially supported by the chimney, as a hanging rafter/beam terminates into it. Should this be a concern to demoing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the rafter is , or can be, supported by the house wall, if that is the case just ensure that it is well attached and begin demolition by removing bricks from the top.